# react native a11y: should every Touchable have an explicit accessibilityRole assigned?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, accessibility, voiceover

the [react native a11y docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/accessibility#accessible) mention that all `Touchable`s are `accessible=true` by default, which means they group all the labels within, and announce as one single label.

That said, it seems `Touchable`s are not announced as interactive on VoiceOver by default, while Talkback announces "Double tap to activate" when a touchable is focused, voiceover treats it as any other text element, and does not announce anything in particular about interactivity.

This leads me to think that may be we should add an accessibilityRole to all Touchables by default? Is this thought process correct? I can't seem to find any documentation around this.